# Separar palabras en una nueva columna en R

Tags: r, dataframe

Tengo un Data Frame parecido a este

```
y<-c(" Golden State WarriorsGSW ", " Brooklyn NetsBKN", "Philadelphia 76ersPHI")
```

¿De qué manera podría separar las tres letras finales que están en mayúsculas y crear una nueva columna?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si esas tres letras siempre están al final de la cadena lo más fácil es hacer por posiciones.

```
y <-c (" Golden State WarriorsGSW ", 
       " Brooklyn NetsBKN", 
       "Philadelphia 76ersPHI") 

library(tidyverse) #Carga stringr que tienes las funcioones str_*

y <- str_squish(y) #Elimino espacio en blanco  al pcipio y al final, si no podrían estar movidas las posiciones. 

código <- str_sub( y, -3, -1) #Captura los tres último caracteres
nombre <- str_sub(y, 1, -4) # Captura desde el primer caracter hasta el -4, justo antes de empezar el código.
```

Quizás se puede encontrar una función de split por posición, pero estas funciones son bien simples al poder usar el signo menos y tomar como referencia al final de la cadena.

Si estás trabajando dentro de un data.frame sería más conveniente `tidyr::separate()`.

```
tibble(y=y) %>% 
  mutate(y = str_squish(y)) %>% 
  separate(y, into = c("nombre", "código"), -3)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
nombre                código
 <chr>                 <chr> 
1 Golden State Warriors GSW   
2 Brooklyn Nets         BKN   
3 Philadelphia 76ers    PHI
```

Comment: Muchas gracias mpaladino. Si, estoy trabajando con tidyverse

Answer (score 2):

Lo podrías resolver con un poco de patrones regulares:

```
unlist(regmatches(y, regexec("[[:upper:]]{3}\\b", y)))

[1] "GSW" "BKN" "PHI"
```

El patrón `"[[:upper:]]{3}\\b"` representa la coincidencia de 3 letras mayúsculas junto con el final de una palabra. El uso combinado de `regmatches()` y `regexec()` permiten extraer las palabras deseadas.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Patricio